# notifications handling angular 4 with django backend

Tags: django, angular, django-rest-framework

i am using following django app for generating notifications
https://github.com/django-notifications/django-notifications. It gives usage instructions for simple html and javascript, but angular won't understand those tags out of box. How can i achieve this with angular 4?

Answer (score 0):

Since Angular will render your templates, you must get that information from api request, so this template tags wont work.

Check if this lib provide apis or try to create one api by yourself and override this lib if is possible